# how to set bootstrap border for left and right side and fade top and bottom parts

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to generate a border for the box. Where border appears only on the sides.

I need to fade the border in the top and bottom.

I tried using Box shadow and border but no luck. Can someone guide me on this.

Comment: Post what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
[selector]  {
    border-left: 5px solid #ff0000;
border-right: 5px solid #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: i need fade out in the top and bottom.

Comment: fadeout means? When hover or clicked the border in top and bottom should disappear..or..

Comment: the border will be lighter in the top slowly it will be darker and then again goes to lighter side. Border is fixed no changes on hover or click. The border is for div tag

Comment: <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 box-shadow-preview">
 

 </div>

Comment: .box-shadow-preview{ 
    position: relative; 
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    border-width: 1px; 
    border-style: solid; 
    border-color: #DDDDDD; 
    border-radius: 0px; 
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px #99a3ad, 0px 0px 40px #eeeeee; 
}

Comment: .box-shadow-preview:before{ 
    content: ""; 
    z-index: -1; 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 95%; 
    top: 10px; 
    right: 0px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
    left: 0px; 
    border-radius: 0px; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #2a2e31; 
} 

.box-shadow-preview:after{ 
    content: ""; 
    z-index: -1; 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 95%; 
    top: 10px; 
    right: 0px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
    border-radius: 0px; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #2a2e31; 
}

Comment: the column has two rows with images

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
.divName {
border-top: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
border-right: 4px solid #333333;
border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
border-left: 4px solid #333333;}
```